# How would I avoid using Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the below snippet of code, designed to check if a message was sent to a phone number:

```
public static boolean checkMessages(long sendTime, String phone) {
    boolean gotMessage = false;

    while (!gotMessage) {
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        gotMessage = MessageHandler.getResponse(sendTime, phone);
    }
    return gotMessage;
}
```

This code itself is called through a `CompletableFuture`, so it can run in parallel with another check. If neither check is satisfied within a certain amount of time, both will expire.

Now, according to my IDE and this site, using `Thread.sleep()` is bad for a number of reasons, so I'd like to remove it from my code somehow.

Is there a way to do this such that this method will only ever return true, like it currently is?

---

`MessageHandler.getResponse()` is a handler I wrote to check if I received a text message containing a specific (hardcoded) string of text from a specific phone number. It does block execution until it finishes checking, but the API I'm using has very aggressive rate limits. The API offers no callbacks -- it must manually be called.

Comment: What is MessageHandler? What communications package are you using?

Comment: @ccleve MessageHandler is a custom class I wrote to interface with the API I'm using, which is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: This sounds like a case where you should use a callback that gets invoked when the message arrives rather than polling for one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not very clear what your whole code does. As commented by others, knowing what `MessageHandler` does would add some context.

The `Thread.sleep` static invocation will make the current thread sleep for at least the given amount of time,

> subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers

(see [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29))

If your `MessageHandler.getResponse` invocation blocks before returning, then you probably don't need to sleep at all.

However, if this task is repeated "endlessly", you probably want to use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead, and run it based on a schedule.

Bottomline, `Thread.sleep` is not "bad practice" per se, but you seldom need to actually use it.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with Mena's response, but to offer an alternate implementation to Thread.sleep, you can use a CountdownLatch to perform your looping:

```
public void blockingWaitForMessage(long sendTime, String phone) throws InterruptedException{
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        while (!latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            if (MessageHandler.getResponse(sendTime, phone)) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }
```

Using *CountDownLatch.await* handles both your boolean and temporal states!

Answer (score 0):

You can use guava retrying library. 
[Retryer](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying/blob/master/README.md)
It has nice API.

Or you can decorate [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) from Java library.